# Why can't I use .orElseThrow() method on an Entity?

Tags: spring, controller

The following method works.

```
@GetMapping("/usuarios/{codigo_us}")
EntityModel<Usuario> one(@PathVariable Long codigo_us) { //HATEOAS way of forwarding resources
    Usuario usuario = repository.findById(codigo_us)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsuarioNotFoundException(codigo_us));
    // Spring WebMvcLinkBuilder
    return assembler.toModel(usuario);
}
```

But when I try a slightly different approach it doesn't work.

```
@GetMapping("/usuarios/{cedula_us}")
EntityModel<Usuario> getByCedula(@PathVariable Long cedula_us){
    Usuario usuario = repository.findByCedula_us(cedula_us).get(0)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsuarioNotFoundException(cedula_us));
    return assembler.toModel(usuario);
```

Answer (score 3):

Different classes have different methods available.

The first method returns an `Optional<Usuario>` which has method `orElseThrow()`

The second method returns some kind of Iterable/List/Collection, on which you call get(0) which grabs the first element `Usuario`but no longer wrapped in Optional. Therefore there is no `orElseThrow()` available.

You can achieve the same thing for second method by wrapping it into optional:

```
Usario usario = repository.findByCedula_us(cedula_us).get(0);
usario = Optional.ofNullable(usario).orElseThrow(...
```

This is just an example to clarify how it works, a better approach would be to add a method in the repository itself to only return first result and return optional, something like:

```
Optional<Usario> findFirstByCedula_us(String cedula_us)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `findByCedula_us` method is not optional it should be like this

```
Optional<Usario> findByCedula_us(Long cedula_us);
```